# Dúvida em listar itens com PDO e PHP 7

Tags: mysql, pdo

Olá, estou tentando fazer uma listagem utilizando o PHP 7 E PDO e não estou conseguindo.
Até então fiz esse código

```
<?php
$con = new PDO("mysql: dbname = banco; host = localhost", "root", "senha");
$sql = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM turmas WHERE status='Ativo' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 12");
$sql->execute();
$row = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (count($row) === 0 ) {
    echo "<option disabled>Nenhuma Turma Cadastrada</option>";
    } else {
        while ($row){
    ?>
    <option value="<? echo $row['turma']?>"> MED <? echo $row['turma']?> </option>
    <?php
}}
?>
```

Sendo que existem 12 registros na tabela turmas, porém quando vou ao site, ele diz que não existe nenhuma turma cadastrada.

Alguém poderia me ajudar

Comment: Logo após `$sql->execute();` coloque a linha `print_r($sql->errorInfo());` e nos passe o resultado.

Comment: Já tentou rodar a consulta "SELECT * FROM turmas WHERE status='Ativo' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 12" diretamente no banco de dados pra confirmar se ela está retornando resultados?

Comment: O método `prepare` do PDO deve ser usado para preparar uma consulta para receber os parâmetros com `bindParam`, não é o seu caso, pode usar o método `query` em substituição que deve funcionar.

Answer (score -1):

Consegui resolver com esse código

```
<?php
$con = new PDO("mysql:dbname=banco;host=localhost", "root", "senha");
$sql = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM turmas WHERE status = 'Ativo' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 12");
$sql->execute();

$row = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (count($row) === 0 ) {
    echo "<option disabled>Nenhuma Turma Cadastrada</option>";
}
else {
    foreach($row as $data) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?=$data['turma']?>"> MED <?=$data['turma']?> </option>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```